# Workflow: send message when value "user" changed in reservation list

Tags: 2010, list, workflow

We have a reservation list for mobile devices. When the values "user" or "status" changed I would like to send a message to the former user. What do you guys advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with two hidden columns and two workflows.

Call the two hidden columns `user_hidden` and `status_hidden`.

Develop a first workflow that starts when the item is *created*. This workflow will set the value of `user_hidden` to be equal to `user` and set the value of `status_hidden` to be equal to `status`.

Develop a second workflow that starts when the item is *changed*. This workflow will look something like this:

1. Get the values of `user`, `status`, `user_hidden` and `status_hidden`
2. If `user` is not equal to `user_hidden` or `status` is not equal to `status_hidden`, we know one of the fields has been changed, so do stuff
3. Set the value of `user_hidden` to be equal to `user` and set the value of `status_hidden` to be equal to `status`, ready for the next time the item is changed.